# Selecting each distinct duplicate with ID from a list of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using the following query to find duplicate records in a table based on the fullname. 
Now I need to select 1 distinct conntactid from the duplicates based on the fullname. 
Here is what I have:

```
select c.namefml from contact c
where c.contactrecordtype = 'CONTACT'
group by c.namefml
HAVING COUNT (c.namefml)>1
```

However, I cannot seem to use this a sub-query to select the distinct contact-id based on the first name, If i do, it lists the contact-ids of all the duplicates since the contact-id is unique for all for all of the duplicate contacts. There are approximately 180 distinct duplicate contacts but 445 duplicates all together.

How would i get a distinct contact-id/contact full name based on the full name of the duplicate contact.

Comment: Please show us subset of the data and an expected result, it's quite too much abstract.

Comment: Try `SELECT MIN(c.contact-id)` and then use it in a sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to select a value that is duplicate, `namefml` in this case, and then use it in a sub query to filter records. So the query is bound to return all records that match the condition.

Instead try using `MIN` or `MAX` to get ids that are distinct in the table, and then use it in a sub query to get the desired result. Try something like

```
SELECT MIN(c.contact-id)...
```

Answer (score 2):

As your name is your relevant information, pick any ID using MIN or MAX:

```
WITH        Sample AS
(
            SELECT 1 ID, 'ABC' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 'ABC' Name UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 'XYZ' Name
)
SELECT      MIN(ID) MinID, Name, COUNT(*) Duplicates
FROM        Sample
GROUP BY    Name
```

Result

```
MinID   Name    Duplicates
    1   ABC     2
    3   XYZ     1
```